Problem with flet apk for android, not working alignment for android
Problem with Flet in python, I was developing an app for android tablet, in my pc, when I try "flet run" everything is fine, but for android "flet run --android -r" when I check from tablet, alignments are not working, animation is not working as supposed, is there any way to fix that?
link to project: https://github.com/xelland042/flet_test
